# Remove performance warning in C++ template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, boost, compiler-warnings

I want to remove a float to bool conversion performance warning in a function of a template class, and `boost::enable_if` feels like overkill in this case.

Is there maybe a way to check the type of the template in compile time and then use the appropriate casting depending on the type?

```
    T val;
    float val2;
    val = (T)(val+val2); // warning here for objects of type bool
```

I want something like this:

```
    #if (boost::is_same<CType, bool>::value == true)
        val = (val+val2)!=0;
    #else
        val = (T)(val+val2);
    #endif
```

I would prefer not to just disable the warning.

Edit: Added visual studio tag

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Compler warnings are specific to the compiler you are using. Please tag this question appropriately to your compiler.

Comment: You could specialize the template for bool types.

Comment: Thanks Colin, but creating a specialization to fix one warning seems like a bit of an overkill to me. Surely there must be a more convenient way?

Comment: `val = (val+val2)!=0;` will not work the way you expect it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why can't you do what you're doing in the code you want? You can create that exact block of code with `is_same`.

Comment: FWIW, once you've started doing computations on floating-point numbers, testing them for equality with anything is unreliable.  They have a tendency to pick up very small errors that often mean absolutely nothing except that they throw off equal conditions.

Comment: @Mike Seymour's answer is correct as long as you deal with template function.
If you've created the template class, the partial specialization is the solution.

Answer (score 6):

You could pull the operation out into a separate template, and overload for `bool`:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 add(T1 const & v1, T2 const & v2) {
    return static_cast<T1>(v1 + v2);
}

template <typename T2>
bool add(bool v1, T2 const & v2) {
    return (v1 + v2) != 0;
}

T val;
float val2;
val = add(val,val2); // hopefully no warning now.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `is_same` with an if-block to 'specialize' for bool. It's part of the standard library, in case you didn't want to use Boost's.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T val1) {
    T val;
    float val2;

    if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value == true)
        val = (val1 + val2) != 0;
    else
        val = val1 + val2;
}
```

Because it's a template function, I would expect the compiler to optimize out the branch, achieving the same result as if it were a real template specialization.